# JBoss out of memory error

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I tried to terminate the current JBoss session using `Control + c` on the command line.

Now when i try to start the server, I get

```
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Comment: Your issue title "JBoss out of memory error" does not appear to accurately describe the actual issue you have described - Address already in use.

Answer (score 0):

Control-C probably didn't terminate the previous process cleanly.

If you're running this on Windows then use the Task Manager to find the old JBoss process and kill it. The process will be listed as `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`

If its Linux use `ps -ef | grep standalone.sh` to find the process id and then kill it.